# How to make MVVM property changed when my settings also changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ViewModel like this

```
Public class AboutPageViewModel
{
  public AboutPageViewModel()
  {
    AppName = Settings.MyAppName;
  }

  private string _appName;
  public string AppName
  {
    get{return _appName;}
    set{_appName = value; RaisePropertyChanged("AppName");}
  }
}
```

Now in a static class

```
public static class Settings
{
   public static string MyAppName{get;set;} = "LOL"
}
```

How do I notify the ViewModel everytime  MyAppName is changed, and update it to the Binded UI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As you define it in your question, `Settings` isn't a static class (ah, I see in comments that was a typo, and it's static in your code). It should not be static. PropertyChanged notifications on a static class are theoretically possible but it's not worth your time to mess with, and there's no need to bother.

Have `Settings` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, just like your viewmodel. When `MyAppName` changes, `Settings` should raise `PropertyChanged`, just as `AboutPageViewModel` does when its own `AppName` property changes.

Now give `Settings` a static property called `Instance`:

```
public static Settings Instance { get; private set; }

static Settings()
{
    Instance = new Settings();
}
```

And handle its `PropertyChanged` event in `AboutPageViewModel`:

```
public AboutPageViewModel()
{
    AppName = Settings.Instance.MyAppName;
    Settings.Instance.PropertyChanged += (s,e) =>
    {
        //  If you're in C#6:
        //if (e.PropertyName == nameof(Settings.MyAppName))
        if (e.PropertyName == "MyAppName")
        {
            AppName = Settings.Instance.MyAppName;
        }
    }
}
```

## Option Number Two

Arguably a better option; I've done it this way more than once.

In comments, @MikeEason makes the very good point that this could also be done with a custom `*Changed` event such as `MyAppNameChanged`, which has two advantages: It lets you go back to a static class, and it lets you skip the check on the property name, which is extra code and also a ["magic string"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_string). Working with `INotifyPropertyChanged` we get a little bit numb to the danger of magic strings, but they are in fact bad. If you're in C#6, you can and absolutely should use the `nameof()` operator, but not all of us are in C#6 just yet. My main responsibility at work is an application that we're *hoping* to migrate to C#6 this summer.

```
public static event EventHandler<String> MyAppNameChanged;

private static String _myAppName = "";
public static String MyAppName {
    get { return _myAppName; }
    set {
        if (_myAppName != value)
        {
            _myAppName = value;
            //  C#6 again. Note (thanks OP!) you can't pass this for sender 
            //  in a static property. 
            MyAppNameChanged?.Invoke(null, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The drawback of this is that, well, this class is called `Settings`, not `Setting`. Maybe it's got a dozen properties changing here and there. That gets to be a real thicket of distinct property-changed events ("so what?" you may ask -- and you may have a point). My tendency is to stick with `PropertyChanged` if there's a whole sheaf of them, and to add an event if the class has only one or two important properties that somebody needs to keep an eye on. Either way is annoying in my view; try both and you'll eventually settle on a preference.

Comment: Perhaps a `MyAppNameChanged` dedicated **event** might be a better idea? This will allow you to prevent having to check the property name on `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Settings is a static class. I forgot to add this.

Comment: @MikeEason That's quite true. And it's more than just an extra three lines of code too, it's a Magic String. The question is whether he might be tracking more than one different property on a class called `Settings`; my unmentioned assumption was that he would be. In that case, it starts to be a burden to add a new event for each property that might change. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: to add events for my Settings class is an idea but I thought there might be another way

Comment: I suggest using `nameof` in C#6.

Comment: @codran Absolutely.

Comment: I'm torn. Subscribing to `PropertyChanged` works, but it definitely feels like a hack. I would probably go down the route of events.

Comment: @MikeEason Events is probably better, all things considered. Thing is, `PropertyChanged` is such a pervasive idiom in XAML; in spite of its obvious shortcomings, "this is how we did everything else" is not the worst excuse for doing something. And it's always nice to be able to say "hey, it's a viewmodel, let's stuff it in a dialog".

Comment: @MikeEason Gotta say your edit Conflicts With My Intent. I have an aversion to event handlers that use arguments not derived from `EventArgs`: it violates What Would the Framework Do? In this case if I weren't passing plain `EventArgs`, I'd use a generic subclass `ValueChangedEventArgs<T>` with `T OldValue` and `T NewValue` properties. I didn't want to hit OP with code that wasn't strictly necessary -- especially if `Settings` is static; no question which instance changed. But I ain't gonna start a war about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found it very annoying when I have dozens of properties to monitor. Here I found a PRISM MVVM library which can keep an eye on this. Will try different ways and find a better solution.  Thanks again

Comment: PS. An static class I think MyAppNameChanged?.Invoke(this, value); "this" is not allowed. Right?

Comment: @CagayaCoper Whoops! Right you are.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to *store* value in ViewModel if you already have it somewhere (I assume what you are not going to change it in ViewModel itself):

```
public class AboutPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string AppName => Settings.MyAppName;
}
```

And as for View to know when this property is changed you need 2 things: 1) there should be a way to inform ViewModel when value is changed 2) rise `PropertyChanged(nameof(AppName))` (notice `INotifyPropertyChanged`).

Several possibilities to make it:

1. `Settings` should rise event when `MyAppName` value is changed, ViewModel subscribe to it and rises `PropertyChanged`;
2. Store initial value, check periodically if value is changed;
3. Use another type which implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, bind to that type property instead, this will update view automatically if that type rises `PropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface on Settings class!

then use the same piece of code like this:

```
  private string _myAppName;
  public string MyAppName
  {
    get{return _myAppName;}
    set{_appName = value; RaisePropertyChanged("MyAppName");}
  }
```